# Puppeteer: return JSON response of AJAX response

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

while the page is loading I am trying to wait for a certain AJAX request made by my page and then return its response's JSON body. My code does not stop iterating through every response even after the condition is met within the listener for 'response' event.

Once I find the response I want to return, how can I capture the JSON from the response, stop execution the page from loading further, and return my JSON?

```
async function runScrape() {
    const browser = await browserPromise;
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
    
    let apiResponse;
    page.on('response', async response => {
        let url = await response.url();
        let status = await response.status();
        console.info(status + " NETWORK CALL: " + url);
        if ( url.match(requestPattern) ) {
            apiResponse = await response.text();
            await page.evaluate(() => window.stop());
        }
    });
    
    await page.goto(req.query.url);
    console.log("API RESPONSE:\n" + apiResponse);
    return apiResponse
}}
```

**=== UPDATE ===**

This was the solution that ended up working. It seemed this approach was required due to the specific behavior of the page being scraped.

```
async function runScrape() {
    const browser = await browserPromise;
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    
    let JSONResponse;
    page.on('response', async response => {
        if ( !JSONResponse && response.url().match(requestPattern) ) {
            JSONResponse = await response.text();
        }
    });

    page.on('request', request => {
        if (request.resourceType() === 'image' || request.resourceType() === 'stylesheet') request.abort()
        else request.continue()
    });
    
    await page.goto(scrapeURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.close();
    return JSONResponse
}

runScrape()
.then( response => {
    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    res.status(200).send(response);
})
.catch(err => {
    let payload = {"errorType": err.name, "errorMessage": err.message+"\n"+err.stack};
    console.error(JSON.stringify(payload));
    res.status(500).json(payload);
});
```

Comment: It's better to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than edit your answer into the question. If your solution is dependent on specific behavior of the page being scraped, it's a good idea to share that page or at least a minimal mock of the page so others can understand what the problem/solution really was.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify it to a single `page.on('response'...` where we are looking for the desired request pattern with [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Once the response is identified then we can emulate the *"Stop loading this page"* button of the browser with `await page.evaluate(() => window.stop())`. The [`window.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop) method won't close the browser yet, just stops the network requests.

```js
let resp
page.on('response', async response => {
  if (response.url().includes(requestPattern)) {
    resp = await response.json()
    await page.evaluate(() => window.stop())
    }
  })

await page.goto(req.query.url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' } )
console.log(resp)
```

### Edit:

To avoid `undefined` response you should use `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'` setting on `page.goto()`, see [the docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pagegotourl-options) about the options. You've got `undefined` because by default puppeteer considered page to be loaded when the `load` event is fired on the page (this is the default setting of `waitUntil`). So if the page considered loaded but there are still network connections in the queue and your request pattern is not found yet: the script will go on from `goto` to `console.log`. So you make sure the request is registered before it would happen by waiting until all network request has been finished.

> `networkidle0`: consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 0 network connections for at least 500 ms.

**Please note:** by setting networkidle you won't be able to disconnect after the request pattern condition was fulfilled, so your plan to stop the responses won't be possible.

I recommend to abort those [`resourceType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/ResourceType)s which are not needed, like this you may have similar results as you would with stopping the requests:

**For example:**

Place it right after the `page.on('response', async response => {...` block ended.

```js
  await page.setRequestInterception(true)
  page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'image' || request.resourceType() === 'stylesheet') request.abort()
    else request.continue()
  })
```

You can use it with a `request.url().includes(unwantedRequestPattern)` condition as well if you know which connections you don't need.

Comment: Thanks @theDavidBarton, I am still receiving responses from the page even after `await page.evaluate(() => window.stop())` is run. I realize their corresponding requests might had been launched before the window.stop() was run, but there seems to be quite a lot still happening.  Also, I am consistently seeing the JSON response is undefined. Ive also tried with `await response.text()` and it is still undefined, despite the fact that response.status() == 200.  Is there some reason my code might not be loading the body of the response?

Comment: See my update. Unfortunately you cannot do the both at the same time. Either you make sure that your required request is awaited (but its price is that you need to wait all network connections to be resolved) or you stop once it is found, but if it arrives after the page is loaded it won't be registered. See my edited answer above: I offered a workaround which may helps to achieve similar results.

Comment: Thanks @theDavidBarton. You led me down the right track, but using the solution above still yielded 'undefined' for the JSON response because apparently the page retries this same AJAX request a few times so I had to add logic back into the response handler to only grab the response if `!resp && response.url().includes(requestPattern)`.  Also, I had to take out the `window.stop()` as it was causing the page to make more requests somehow.  I'll post my working solution in the question.

Comment: Great! I am glad you've figured out a solution that fits the current case :)